# Deploy Udash demo app to NGINX

Tags: nginx, sbt, udash

How can I deploy the Udash framework demo outside of SBT, and run it under NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is lame, but I am able to run under NGINX with this line:

nohup sbt -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal run &

and these location mappings:

```
location /notifications/ {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:12345;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}

location /atm/ {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location /frontend/ {
    proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:12345;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass       http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```